# Macro not in the list after loading the add-in

Tags: vba, excel, excel-addins

I have a created a macro show() and saved it as display.xla and open a new workbook and added the display add-in. But when i went to Tools->Macro->Macro.. its not the list, But if i type display.xla!show and click run im able to execute it.

Is there anyway to display the macros stored in the Add-in.? Apart from having it in personal.xls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you declared the show macro as a function, or have Option Private Module at the start of the head of the module? Either will stop it showing in the macro list.